# LINQ List query for contents of another list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have List _locationData that contains a unique identifier uid which is a string. I want to use a LINQ query to return a List that have a uid that is contained within a List uids.

```
  public IQueryable<Location> FindAll(List<string> uids)
    {
        return _locationData.AsQueryable().Where(z => z.uid.Any(v => uids.Equals(v)));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
public IQueryable<Location> FindAll(List<string> uids)
{
    return _locationData.AsQueryable().Where(z => uids.Contains(z.uid));
}
```

This checks if for each element in your location data, it's contained in the list `uids`. if so, then the location will be included in the result that will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Contains` on the list:

```
return _locationData.AsQueryable().Where(z => uids.Contains(z.uid));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't strictly need the result to be IQueryable and that was just a convenience for what linq was returning from where, you could do this:

```
private List<Location> FindAll(List<string> uids)
{
    return _locationData.FindAll(location => uids.Contains(location.uid));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a join like this:

```
public IQueryable<Location> FindAll(List<string> uids)
{
    return _locationData.AsQueryable().Join(uids, l => l.uid.ToString(), s => s, (l, s) => l);
}
```